# MongoDB BSON - Search on specific fields

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

With MongoDB I can do the following:

```
db.collection.find({}, {"select_just_this_field": 1})
```

But how I can do the same with MongoDB + BSON (GoLang) - Something like:

```
bson.M{{}, {"select_just_this_field": 1}}
```

Comment: What driver are you using? What have you tried? Please include your attempt and the problems you're facing.

Comment: I´m using go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo I want to just select specific fields from Mongo and append the results to a existing struct